# "cannot convert from db_shoes.Koneksi to string"

Tags: c#, mysql

```
MySqlConnection dbcon = new MySqlConnection(koneksi2);

MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query,dbcon);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telp", telp);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", mail);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
int count = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (count > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Your Account Has Been Succsess Added");
    // reset textbox
    txtName.Text = "";
    txtAddress.Text = "";
    txtTelp.Text = "";
    txtMail.Text = "";
    txtUsername.Text = "";
    txtPassword.Text = "";
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to create your new account, Please try again!!");
}
```

The error from this syntax is = "cannot convert from db_shoes.Koneksi to string"

can you explain and help me for this error?

i tried to connect my db but cannot connect. After i run the file, there some popup and the text is connection must be valid and open. After that, error has shown on my code

the code using C#

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this example code I use to add data to a Database dbName

```
public static string dbName = "AFriends.db";
```

This is declared top level Have a look at this code construction and note USING

```
        public void saveData()
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection($"Data Source = '{dbName}';Version=3;"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "INSERT INTO FriendsData " +
                        "   (fxFirstName, fxLastName, fxAddress, fxCity, fxState, fxZip, fxCellPhone, fxEmail, fxInfo) " +
                        "   VALUES " +
                        "   (@fxFirstName, @fxLastName, @fxAddress, @fxCity, @fxState, @fxZip, @fxCellPhone, @fxEmail, @fxInfo)";

            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                try
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxFirstName", fn);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxLastName", ln);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxAddress", ad);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxCity", ct);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxState", st);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxZip", zp);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxCellPhone", ph);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxEmail", em);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fxInfo", rt);

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    result = ex.ToString();
                    tbMessage.Text = result;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```